# Find gtk icon paths without gtk (how gtk find the default theme and icons?)

Tags: icons, find, gtk

I need to use the system default icons but im not using gtk nor qt.. I need something like

find_icon('icon_name', [icon_size]) => '/usr/share/icons/...'

PD: Im using nodejs but i want to know how to find the icons to use them in any other language.

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

access the dconf or gconf from command line shell (provided the language has function to access shell like C,Python,Perl, etc). then ask what desktop environment you are on than find the settings. gnome and kde share the same default folder in the root, but not if you set icon default on the home folder.